# How do I include a break in a string in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, nunjucks

To simplify things, I'm writing code using Nunjucks where I am passing a collection of strings to a function, where that function will then display those strings. Something like this:

```
{% macro Function(strings) %}
   {% for item in strings %}
      <div>{{ item.string }}</div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{% set example = [
   {string: 'Hello,'},
   {string: 'it is nice'},
   {string: 'to meet you!'}
]%}

{{ Function(strings=example)}}
```

I want to be able to add a break tag or new line character in some of these strings, but every time I do the new line isn't displayed. It'll end up like this:

```
input: {string: 'it is\nnice'}
output: it is nice
```

or this:

```
input: {string: 'it is<br>nice'}
output: it is<br>nice
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [nl2br](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but with a little more structure and tooling with your macros, and the built in 'safe' filter, you can pull it off...

#### Using a loop to display your full predefined set:

```bash
{# STEP 1 - define your strings the way you want with set...#}
{% set mStrings = [
   {stringval: 'Hello,'},
   {stringval: 'it is<br> nice'},
   {stringval: 'to meet you!'}
]%}

{# STEP 2 - create a macro function to help display/decor the data back into our template #}
{# notice the use of 'safe' to allow your string to not be esacped #}
{% macro collection(gStrings) %}
  <ul>
    {% for gString in gStrings %}
      <li>{{ gString.stringval|safe }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endmacro %}

{# STEP 3 - finally, from within your template, call your macro function, with the correct parameter, like so!...
{{collection(gStrings=mStrings)}}
#}
```

#### Adding custom parameter string data on the fly :

```bash
{# With a lighter approach, start our with your macro function...#}
{% macro entry(entryItem) %}
      {{ entryItem|safe }}
{% endmacro %}

{# from within your template, call your macro function, with the correct parameter, like so!... #}
{{entry("lets say<br>something")}}
{{entry("lets eat<br>something")}}
...etc...
```